# numpy get top k elements from last dimension of ndarray

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

I have a multidimensional array, and I need to get the top k elements from each row of the last dimension.

```
>>> x = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, size=(2,1,1,5))
>>> x
array([[[[99, 39, 10, 18, 68]]],
       [[[22,  3, 13, 56,  2]]]])
```

I'm trying to get:

```
array([[[[ 99.,  68.]]],
       [[[ 18.,  99.]]]])
```

I can get the indices using the following, but I'm not sure how to slice out the values.

```
>>> k = 2
>>> parts = np.flip(-1 - np.arange(k), 0)
>>> indices = np.flip(
...     np.argpartition(x, parts, axis=-1)[..., -k:],
...     axis=-1)
>>> indices
array([[[[0, 4]]],
       [[[3, 0]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem.

```
np.sort(x, axis=len(x.shape)-1)[...,-2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.partition(x, 2)[..., -2:]
```

returns 2 largest elements from each row. E.g.,

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, size=(2,1,1,5))
print(x)
print(np.partition(x, 2)[..., -2:])
```

prints something like

```
[[[[79 34 90 80 56]]]
 [[[78 11 24 20 42]]]]

[[[[80 90]]]
 [[[78 42]]]]
```